# Blazor: Can I add thousand separator when using @variable to print values on the page?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-client-side

For example, in a code like this,

```
<p>Size = @Size</p>

@code {
long Size = 1234567890;
}
```

can I print the value like "1,234,567,890"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<button @onclick="Demo">Click</button>
<span>@stringSize</span>

@code {

    long  size = 1234567890;
    string stringSize = "";

    private void Demo()
    { 
        stringSize = (size).ToString("#,##0.00");
    }

}
```